# can't find solution for my Java Game

Tags: java, oop, javafx, logic, mvp

For school i have to make a game that already exists. 
this is the link to the game: [Game link](http://www.gamesloon.com/free-puzzle-7/logic-games-46/cow-run-iq-marathon-476.html)

a short explanation: each level you receive( on the right side of the screen) a set of arrows that you can place on the screen and when you push the "Go" button the cow starts to move. When he moves on a arrow he will change his direction in the direction of that arrow. So you have to guide the cow with the arrow to his end destination ( a trophy) without touching any obstacles ( like a wall or a tree ... ).

We MUST implement the Model-View-Presenter design pattern. 
So i started with my model because that's my game logic.

***my problem:***
every level should be read with a simple .txt file
here under a example of my level 1:

```
26,6
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xGRGGBGxGGRGGGGGGGGGGBGGTx
xGGGGRGGGGFGxGGGGGGGGGGGGx
xGFGGLGGGGGGGLGGGGGGGGGGGG
xGGGGSGGGxGGGGGGxGGGGGGGGx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

x=obstacle 
G=grass
T=trophy
S= Start position of the cow
L= Fixed left arrow  
R= Fixed right arrow
F= fixed front arrow
B= fixed back arrow
```

i read the file and with a case statement place every char in a line (every char represents an object) in a 2D array.

***My problem is:*** that you have 2 sets of Arrows: a FixedArrow(It's already on the field and you can't change it's position) and a VariableArrow(the arrows on the right side of the screen where the user can place them on the field, if the field is free or with other words if it's on a Grass object.
but how can i do this? how can i create an seperate screen where i can put arrows that the user can put on the field?

i know that my explanation is vague so i hope you guys open the link i posted above and play 1 level so you understand better what i mean.

i'll post a part of my code and class diagram here under.
path= is the path to the .txt file i explained here above.

[My Class Diagramm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0k4J.png)

```
public class Board {
private Tile[][] tiles;

    public Board(Path path) {

        try {

            int yRow = 0;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);
            String[] split = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
            tiles = new Tile[Integer.parseInt(split[1])][Integer.parseInt(split[0])];
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();

                for (int xRow = 0; xRow < line.length(); xRow++) {
                    char character = line.charAt(xRow);
                    switch (character) {
                        case 'x':
                            tiles[yRow][xRow] = new Tile(new Obstacle());
                            break;
                        case 'G':
                            tiles[yRow][xRow] = new Tile(new Grass());
                            break;
                        case 'S':
                            tiles[yRow][xRow] = new Tile(new Grass());
                            //cow.setStartPosition(xRow,yRow);
                            break;
                        case 'L':
                            tiles[yRow][xRow] = new Tile(new FixedArrow(Direction.LEFT));
                            break;
                        case 'R':
                            tiles[yRow][xRow] = new Tile(new FixedArrow(Direction.RIGHT));
                            break;
                        case 'F':
                            tiles[yRow][xRow] = new Tile(new FixedArrow(Direction.FRONT));
                            break;
                        case 'B':
                            tiles[yRow][xRow] = new Tile(new FixedArrow(Direction.BACK));
                            break;
                        case 'T':
                            tiles[yRow][xRow] = new Tile(new Trophy());
                            break;
                        //How should i read a set of arrows in without placing them in the game field but on the right side of the screen
                    }


                }

                ++yRow;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a broad question, seems like a whole project, and answer will be huge too, please consider to make it specific.

Comment: so if i make it specific:

1) how do i reflect a grid pane on a 2Dimensional array ==> so that 1element of the 2D array is the same as 1 square of a gridpane?


2) is it possible to make 2 different panes on a gridpane? for example to seperate 1 grid pane in a pane left, and a pane right. Pane left represent all the items in the 2D array and right pane where i can put some other objects that the user can drag and drop on the left side ?

Comment: 1 -> Yep that is possible, you can set 2d array nodes (tiles) to the gridpane but each tile should be subclass of Node (like Label, ImageView, Button, etc). 2 -> (2 panes on gridpane)? just use a BorderPane as a parent and set Gridpane in left side and other one in right side of border-pane. 3)-> You have to do hard work and research for drag and dropping tile.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the variable arrows with an input scanner or something else. The variable arrows should be in the two dimension array. You need to compare your variable arrow coordinates from your input with the sign at these points in the array and check if you can put there a new arrow or if its not allowed. If its allowed then replace this sign with your new arrow sign or you reuse your fixed arrow signs.

I hope i've understand your question correctly and this helps :)

Comment: hi,
thanks for reply. The problem is. I have 2 sets of arrows: The fixedArrow, that is put on the field when the level is loaded and the user can't change it. And the VariableArrow that the user can put on the field. I have to work with Gridpane to create the layout. If i read the Variable arrows from my .txt file how do i set them on the right side of the display.